# Polymer with a PHP MVC

Tags: php, .htaccess, model-view-controller, polymer

I just finished writing a website using polymer 1.0+ with a PHP MVC framework on the server.  I am about to start a new project, but I want to use app-router.  Unfortunately to use app-router I have to redirect everything to index.html using my .htaccess file.  But my PHP MVC wants everything to run through its index.php.

It got me thinking.  Should I just write my PHP code as a REST API and have my Polymer code get data via iron-ajax?

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP is mostly only used to access data, this sounds like a pretty sound idea in my opinion. It also opens you up to upgrading or migrating your backend to newer technology since it will only be a data layer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand WHY app-router wants everything to route through `index.html`.  The reason is that it invents other routes which are exposed to the browser that aren't real.  Normally, as you are running the app, that doesn't matter, the browser doesn't attempt to load those url's, the app-router is just putting them into the history.

However, your use may take one of those urls and try and paste it (or get someone else to paste it - having sent it to them via (say) email) into the address bar, or you may have an `<a href=` link on your page and what you want to happen is the app loads from its base location and then the router routes it to the correct place.

So actually `index.html` isn't some magic incantation, its the url that the app is loaded from.  If that happens to be `index.php` then that is what you should use.